# Tshark is displaying "florence" and "eforward" rather than source/destination port numbers

Tags: wireshark, telnet, loopback

I am running rawcap on windows7 loopback adapter.  I have run

```
telnet localhost 2181
```

15 Packets were generated.  In order to view the output I ran

```
wireshark\tshark -r \shared\pcap.pcap
```

And here is the output

```
florence   0.000000    10.0.0.22 -> 255.255.255.255 UDP 138 Source port: 56748  Destination port: florence 56748
florence   0.103006    10.0.0.22 -> 255.255.255.255 UDP 138 Source port: 56748  Destination port: florence 56748
eforward   9.458541    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 52 49435 > eforward [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PE
49435   9.466541    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 52 eforward > 49435 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256
eforward   9.474542    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 40 49435 > eforward [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 49435
florence  12.022688    10.0.0.22 -> 255.255.255.255 UDP 138 Source port: 60846  Destination port: florence 60846
florence  12.083691    10.0.0.22 -> 255.255.255.255 UDP 138 Source port: 60846  Destination port: florence 60846
eforward  13.144752    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 42 49435 > eforward [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=2 49435
49435  13.146752    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 40 eforward > 49435 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=3 Win=7936 Len=0 eforward
eforward  14.877851    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 42 49435 > eforward [PSH, ACK] Seq=3 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=2 49435
49435  14.878851    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 40 eforward > 49435 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=5 Win=7936 Len=0 eforward
49435  14.880851    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 40 eforward > 49435 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=5 Win=7936 Len=0 eforward
eforward  14.881851    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 40 49435 > eforward [ACK] Seq=5 Ack=2 Win=8192 Len=0 49435
eforward  14.881851    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 40 49435 > eforward [FIN, ACK] Seq=5 Ack=2 Win=8192 Len=0 49435
49435  14.882851    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 40 eforward > 49435 [ACK] Seq=2 Ack=6 Win=7936 Len=0 eforward
```

So I do NOT understand this.  I am looking for the port 2181 information. Instead I see .. **florence** .. What does that mean?  And how do I see the correct destination port number??

**UPDATE**  The answer from Guy Harris is on-target (and will be accepted).  I would hava a small further clarification to request here: The corrected output (after adding **-n** to tshark command line) is:

```
2181 117.286708    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 40 60723 > 2181 [ACK] Seq=5 Ack=2 Win=8192 Len=0 60723
2181 117.287708    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 40 60723 > 2181 [FIN, ACK] Seq=5 Ack=2 Win=8192 Len=0 60723
60723 117.287708    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 40 2181 > 60723 [ACK] Seq=2 Ack=6 Win=7936 Len=0 2181
```

So now the destination port (2181) is properly displayed.  But please explain: what is the **40** in this section:

```
TCP 40 2181 > 60723
```

Comment: I suggest reading through the doc: http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html. There are some examples here as well, some of which show how to display ports: http://www.chrisbrenton.org/2009/10/analyzing-packets-with-tshark/. You can use the display filter reference here: http://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters

Comment: Thanks, but the issue here is we are restricted to whatever the output of rawcap is.  tshark on windows is unable to gather loopback adapter traffic.  Therefore, learning about the traffic sniffing capabilities of tshark is probably not applicable. The only way tshark comes into play is in tweaking the way it interprets/displays the output dump from rawcap.

Comment: "but the issue here is we are restricted to whatever the output of rawcap is".  The output of rawcap is a pcap file, which has the raw packet contents, including the port numbers - ***NOT*** the names you're seeing.  "The only way tshark comes into play is in tweaking the way it interprets/displays the output dump from rawcap."  And the way it interprets the dump it is what you want to tweak; see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"florence" and "eforward" correspond to entries in Wireshark's "service" file; the "service" file was originally a UN*X file giving names for port numbers - it's also on Windows, and Wireshark now includes its own "service" file, which it uses to map port numbers to names.

The TShark man page documentation says, in its list of command-line flags:

```
   −n  Disable network object name resolution (such as hostname, TCP and
       UDP port names); the −N flag might override this one.

   −N  <name resolving flags>
       Turn on name resolving only for particular types of addresses and
       port numbers, with name resolving for other types of addresses and
       port numbers turned off.  This flag overrides −n if both −N and −n
       are present.  If both −N and −n flags are not present, all name
       resolutions are turned on.

       The argument is a string that may contain the letters:

       C to enable concurrent (asynchronous) DNS lookups

       m to enable MAC address resolution

       n to enable network address resolution

       N to enable using external resolvers (e.g., DNS) for network
       address resolution

       t to enable transport‐layer port number resolution
```

so if you run it with the "-n" flag, that will turn off transport‐layer port number resolution, so that it won't map port numbers to names.  It also won't map IP addresses to host names; if you want that, run TShark with "-n" and "-N n".

Comment: That is useful info, I am about to try it.

Comment: With some adjustments the above does work. Specifically only -n works on windows (not -N). I have updated OP with small additional question, pls take a look.

Comment: -N probably works, to the extent that it causes TShark to try to resolve the IP addresses to names; however, if that attempt fails, it'll show the address, so it looks the same as it would if network address resolution weren't enabled.  127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.22, and 255.255.255.255 might not resolve to a host name, especially if only DNS is being used.

Answer (score 1):

"What is the 40 in this section?" is an separate question, so I'll give it a separate answer.

TShark is showing you the columns specified in the Wireshark configuration file; you probably have the standard columns, plus a "custom" column for the `tcp.dstport` field, showing the destination TCP port number.  One of the standard columns is the link-layer packet length; that's probably what it's displaying.

Comment: thx, i have awarded. pls consider upvote.